# Set OrderBy on Grouped Query Involving Smart Map Field

Tags: ordering, plugin-smartmap, group, elementquery

I'm working with a Structure of resort locations. Each resort has a field `address` which is a Smart Map field. I'm trying to create an initial display page that groups the resorts based on their state (a Smart Map address part), but I would like to order the output first based on the state and then by resort title.

Something like.

- Arkansas
- Awesome Place
- Best Place
- Alabama
- Alright Place
- Better Place
- Florida

I'm partially there using the following:

```
{% set resorts = craft.entries().section('resortsList').orderBy('title ASC').all() %}
{% set resortsByState = resorts|group('address.state') %}
```

And then outputting the list...

```
{% for state, resortsInState in resortsByState %}
  <h2>{{ state }}</h2>
  {% for resort in resortsInState %}
    <p>{{ resort.link }} - {{ resort.address.state }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me the list grouped by the state and ordered by the resort title which gets me partially there. I've tried adding `address.state` as part of the ordering declaration, but I'm only getting errors (Unknown column 'address.state' in 'order clause'). Is there a proper way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've been able to solve this and figured I'd share what I discovered. The key for each group is the value of the state so really what I was after here was a key sort and just didn't realize it. So I found Michael Rog's "[SuperSort](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort)" plugin which has a twig filter for running a ksort and that addressed it perfectly for me making a small adjustment to use supersort in the response.

```
{% set resorts = craft.entries().section('resortsList').orderBy('title ASC').all() %}
{% set resortsByState = resorts|group('address.state')|supersort('ksort') %}
```

I'm interested in other solutions too that don't require a plugin, but this particular direction got things going for me.

Comment: Nice work! Was going to respond and say exactly this. :)

Comment: There's no other solution at the moment. The address data isn't available as part of the initial SQL query, so you need to handle it separately.

Comment: Okay awesome, thank you so much Lindsey for the confirmation!